# Which fake-GPS app works on BlueStacks?

Tags: android, gps

I've tried several, even the one recommended on their site (http://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/202482968-How-to-Get-Location-for-Tinder-), but the screen just flashes for a second (i.e., there is no effect).